# Restructure xml with recursive nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an issue in SAP PI with an xml with recursive nodes. I have a Container which can have a SubContainer with (another) Container.

**Input xml**

```
<Containers xmlns="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer">
    <Container>
        <Name>INTERIEUR1</Name>
        <Number>1</Number>
        <SSCC>111</SSCC>
        <SubContainers>
            <Container>
                <Id>I1371851</Id>
                <SalesOrderNumber>2012231</SalesOrderNumber>
                <ProductionOrderNumber>I2017658</ProductionOrderNumber>
                <Name>ACCESSOIRE1</Name>
                <Barcode>181001371851</Barcode>
                <Items>
                    <Item>
                        <Id>I8709475</Id>
                        <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
                        <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <Id>I8709476</Id>
                        <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
                        <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    </Item>
                </Items>
            </Container>
            <Container>
                <Id>I1371852</Id>
                <SalesOrderNumber>2012231</SalesOrderNumber>
                <ProductionOrderNumber>I2017658</ProductionOrderNumber>
                <Name>PANEEL1</Name>
                <Barcode>181001371852</Barcode>
                <Items>
                    <Item>
                        <Id>I8709492</Id>
                        <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
                        <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    </Item>
                </Items>
            </Container>
        </SubContainers>
    </Container>
```

Challenge: I want to move the child Container nodes of the SubContainers to the root level and use the value of SSCC in these nodes. Thus getting rid of the SubContainers element.

**Required result**

```
<Containers xmlns="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer">
    <Container>
        <Id>I1371851</Id>
        <SalesOrderNumber>2012231</SalesOrderNumber>
        <ProductionOrderNumber>I2017658</ProductionOrderNumber>
        <Name>ACCESSOIRE1</Name>
        <SSCC>111</SSCC>
        <Barcode>181001371851</Barcode>
        <Items>
            <Item>
                <Id>I8709475</Id>
                <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
                <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Id>I8709476</Id>
                <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
                <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            </Item>
        </Items>
    </Container>
    <Container>
        <Id>I1371852</Id>
        <SalesOrderNumber>2012231</SalesOrderNumber>
        <ProductionOrderNumber>I2017658</ProductionOrderNumber>
        <Name>PANEEL1</Name>
        <SSCC>111</SSCC>
        <Barcode>181001371852</Barcode>
        <Items>
            <Item>
                <Id>I8709492</Id>
                <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
                <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            </Item>
        </Items>
    </Container>
</Container>
</Containers>
</Containers>
```

**My current xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:ext="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer"   exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ext:Name|ext:Number|ext:SSCC|@*" />
    
     <xsl:template match="ext:Containers/ext:Container/ext:SubContainers[ext:Container]"> 
    <xsl:variable name="sscc" select="/ext:Containers/ext:Container/ext:SSCC"/>
      

    <xsl:for-each select="*">
         <xsl:element name="SSCC" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">        
        <xsl:value-of select="$sscc" /></xsl:element>
     <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm not doing a real great job if you look at [my result](https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/?xslt=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20version%3D%221.0%22%20%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%20%0D%0A%20xmlns%3Aext%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.uniconcreation.com%2F2021%2FIvenzaShippingContainer%22%20%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22ext%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20omit-xml-declaration%3D%22yes%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Astrip-space%20elements%3D%22*%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%40*%20%7C%20node%28%29%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%40*%20%7C%20node%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22ext%3AName%7Cext%3ANumber%7Cext%3ASSCC%7C%40*%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22ext%3AContainers%2Fext%3AContainer%2Fext%3ASubContainers%5Bext%3AContainer%5D%22%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22sscc%22%20select%3D%22%2Fext%3AContainers%2Fext%3AContainer%2Fext%3ASSCC%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each%20select%3D%22*%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aelement%20name%3D%22SSCC%22%20namespace%3D%22%7Bnamespace-uri%28%29%7D%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22%24sscc%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fxsl%3Aelement%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy-of%20select%3D%22node%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3CContainers%20xmlns%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.uniconcreation.com%2F2021%2FIvenzaShippingContainer%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CContainer%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CName%3EINTERIEUR1%3C%2FName%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CNumber%3E1%3C%2FNumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CSSCC%3E111%3C%2FSSCC%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CSubContainers%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CContainer%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CId%3EI1371851%3C%2FId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CSalesOrderNumber%3E2012231%3C%2FSalesOrderNumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CProductionOrderNumber%3EI2017658%3C%2FProductionOrderNumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CName%3EACCESSOIRE1%3C%2FName%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBarcode%3E181001371851%3C%2FBarcode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CItems%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CItem%3E%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%20%20%20%20%3CId%3EI8709475%3C%2FId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CSalesOrderRowId%3EI671068%3C%2FSalesOrderRowId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CSalesOrderRowExternalReference%3E1%3C%2FSalesOrderRowExternalReference%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CQuantity%3E1%3C%2FQuantity%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CId%3EI8709476%3C%2FId%3E%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%3CSalesOrderRowId%3EI671068%3C%2FSalesOrderRowId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CSalesOrderRowExternalReference%3E1%3C%2FSalesOrderRowExternalReference%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CQuantity%3E1%3C%2FQuantity%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FItems%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FContainer%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CContainer%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CId%3EI1371852%3C%2FId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CSalesOrderNumber%3E2012231%3C%2FSalesOrderNumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CProductionOrderNumber%3EI2017658%3C%2FProductionOrderNumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CName%3EPANEEL1%3C%2FName%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBarcode%3E181001371852%3C%2FBarcode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CItems%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CId%3EI8709492%3C%2FId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CSalesOrderRowId%3EI671068%3C%2FSalesOrderRowId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CSalesOrderRowExternalReference%3E1%3C%2FSalesOrderRowExternalReference%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CQuantity%3E1%3C%2FQuantity%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FItems%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FContainer%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FSubContainers%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FContainer%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FContainers%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A&input-type=XML) on xsltfiddle :(

I'm stuck with the original parent and I don't manage to get the 2  elements around my child nodes.

Kind regards,

Mike D

Comment: Where is `<SSCC >00387112839033718509</SSCC>` coming from? And what is the meaning of the namespace declaration change from `xmlns="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer"` to `xmlns:ucc="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer"`? And why is the question tagged both as XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Sorry, SSCC 0038xx should be 111. Copy / paste error. Removed xslt 1.0 tag. regarding the ucc prefix, I'm always struggling with the namespaces and at tried several things / ns this morning. Thanks a lot for helping me. I'll try to doublecheck my input better next time. Corrected the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am guessing correctly, all you need to do is simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Containers">
    <xsl:variable name="sscc" select="Container/SSCC"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="//SubContainers/Container">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="* except (Barcode, Items)"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$sscc"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Barcode, Items"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Containers xmlns="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer">
   <Container>
      <Id>I1371851</Id>
      <SalesOrderNumber>2012231</SalesOrderNumber>
      <ProductionOrderNumber>I2017658</ProductionOrderNumber>
      <Name>ACCESSOIRE1</Name>
      <SSCC>111</SSCC>
      <Barcode>181001371851</Barcode>
      <Items>
         <Item>
            <Id>I8709475</Id>
            <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
            <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
         </Item>
         <Item>
            <Id>I8709476</Id>
            <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
            <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
         </Item>
      </Items>
   </Container>
   <Container>
      <Id>I1371852</Id>
      <SalesOrderNumber>2012231</SalesOrderNumber>
      <ProductionOrderNumber>I2017658</ProductionOrderNumber>
      <Name>PANEEL1</Name>
      <SSCC>111</SSCC>
      <Barcode>181001371852</Barcode>
      <Items>
         <Item>
            <Id>I8709492</Id>
            <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
            <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
         </Item>
      </Items>
   </Container>
</Containers>
```

---

If the exact order of the child elements of `Container` does not matter, then it could be even simpler. Instead of:

```
            <xsl:copy-of select="* except (Barcode, Items)"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$sscc"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Barcode, Items"/>
```

you could do:

```
            <xsl:copy-of select="$sscc | *"/>
```

Comment: Your solution works perfect Michael! The order of the containers is not really imporant.

Comment: I am not talking about the order of containers. I am talking about the order of their child elements (Id, SalesOrderNumber, etc. + the added SSCC).

Comment: ok, it's no problem for those elements too.